# GCP: limits & quotas

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops

Help me understand please.
My question is related to resource limits and quotas.

I can see all limits and quotas in the Google console. 
I can also send a request to increase the quota.
All Compute Engine resources are global, regional, or zonal.

My question is this: Can I increase the quotas for all the resources that are provided on the quota page in the console?

```
For example, some quotas that are set by default:
Networks = 50 pieces
Subnetworks = 500 pieces,
In-use IP addresses = 69 pieces, etc.
```

How much can I increase quotas? (quantity). Or does the quantity not matter and I can increase by as much as I want?

```
For example, take In-use IP addresses = 69 pieces.
```

They are 2 kinds: regional and global, do I need to increase both, and manage both? (regional and global) or not ?

This also applies to other resources (for example, Static IP addresses, internal IP addresses), which also come in two forms: regional and global.
do I need to increase both, and manage both? (regional and global) or not ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the majority of Google Products (such as VPC networking as an example), there is detailed documentation on that product.  The format of the documentation seems to be consistent from one product to another.  In the documentation under the "Resources" section (shown in the left panel) there is a section (usually) called "Quotas and limits".  From there you will find a list of all the quotas that apply to that product and a description of what they mean.

For example, [here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota) is the page for VPC resource quotas.

My understanding is that, where applicable, global quotas are distinct from location quotas.

Please realize that the quotas exist for two primary reasons.

The first is to protect you.  If an accident happens and you request 100,000 units of something when you mean to request 10 units of something, a low quota will halt the run-away and you won't accidentally be charged for resource you didn't want.

The second reason is to allow Google to balance and accommodate resources.  If suddenly, every customer all wanted 10,000 compute engines in the same region at the same time, Google would be "out of stock" of available compute engines.  When you request additional quota, this is a flag to Google that you are planning to use more resources.  It allows Google to work with you to determine when you need them and to ensure that sufficient resources are available when you need them.

Quotas that are changeable are a soft limit and can be tweaked by your Google support representative as you desire.